# Error "No module named ipaddress"

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-2.x

Estoy haciendo un programa que envié un mensaje de un xbee a otro xbee con un programa en python. Estoy trabajando en Ubuntu. Cuando trato de ejecutar el código me manda el siguiente error:

```
File "./xbeesend.py", line 2, in <module>
  from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/digi/xbee/devices.py", line 17, in <module>
  from ipaddress import IPv4Address
ImportError: No module named ipaddress
```

**Este es mi código:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from digi.xbee.devices import XBeeDevice

device = XBeeDevice("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600)
device.open()
device.send_data_broadcast("Hello XBee from Python/Ubuntu")
device.close()
```

La versión de python en la que estoy trabajando es la 2.7.12.
¿Alguien sabe por que me manda ese error?

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Saul, en principio xbee solo es compatible con Python 3... https://xbplib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started_with_xbee_python_library.html#python-3

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, entonces tendré que actualizarlo, muchas gracias.

Comment: @FJSevilla tambien cuento con la version 3.6.7 de python, pero el error persiste

Comment: Para aclarar , ipddress es un módulo de la biblioteca estándar de Python 3  (>= 3.3) que no existe en Python 2 (aunque hay ports en PyPi), por eso el error en el import. De cualquier forma actualiza a Python 3, el soporte oficial para Python 2.x termina en 5 meces.

Comment: ¿En Python3.6 tienes el mismo error exacto? ¿Estás seguro de estar llamando a dicho interprete y no a Python2 cuando ejecutas el script? Debes instalar xbee en Python 3.6.7 siguiendo las instrucciones de la pagina que enlazo arriba. Asegurate de instalar en el interprete adecuado, por ejemplo `python3 -m pip install digi-xbee --user` y luego asegurarte de ejecutar tu script con el mismo intérprete.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla, ya funciona